# How does Azure Active Directory authentication for Azure API Apps work?

Tags: authentication, azure

I'm trying to call an Azure API App configured with Azure AD authentication. Assume for the purposes of this question I cannot use the Azure SDK and need to write code to get a token and insert it into the API request.*

I have established that there are two modes - 'client flow' and 'server flow', where client flow entails following at least one redirect to an issuer to get a token, and server flow where the server does this for you. Since I'm talking about doing this in code, following redirects would be possible but fiddly, so I'd prefer to use a mode where the URI or URIs to visit are known ahead of time and return content, rather than redirecting. The following diagram illustrates how the gateway routes all requests.

[image: API app credential flow]

I think the mode I need is client flow, which would go something like:

- Get an access token from the identity provider (which is what? how do I find out where this resides? what is the format of the request I have to send to the IdP?)
- Pass the access token to the gateway (in what format?)
- Receive another token in the gateway response
- Supply this token in a header when making an API request (which header?)

How am I supposed to do this? The Azure documentation doesn't give enough detail about how it works, and expects all users to just use the SDK, which hides what is actually happening.

*The actual reason is that ultimately this will need to be called from BizTalk, which uses the WCF WebHttpBinding to call restful services. I'm writing a custom behaviour to insert a token header into the request, but I need to know how this token should be acquired. It's possible to run arbitrary code in BizTalk but trying to do this makes the solution complicated, and config-only or mostly-config with minimal, loosely-coupled code is the simpler solution*

Answer (score 0):

Just want to understand your scenario better, Because you are going to use it from BizTalk Receive Pipeline, The scenario can be simplified by enabling a customer authentication token right ? Basic username and password for your API you have hosted on the cloud. Does BizTalk want to authenticate it self with tokens for each AD User ?

**To answer some of your questions**

- Get an access token from the identity provider (which is what? how do I find out where this resides? what is the format of the request I have to send to the IdP?)

> > After you have configured your AD configuration, Once you have completed the authentication, I am assuming your are using ASP.Net here, You can find everything you need about the claims on your Thread.CurrentPrincipal, You can convert it to ClaimsPrincipal like so var claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal; and then you will find a lot of good information on this object. Name of the user logged in, list of claims the principal has etc. I have not explored every avenue here, but this should be a good starting point.

Your API App is running on this process which means you have access to these claims in your API App code as well.

I would build a custom pipeline in BizTalk that uses Azure SDK to authenciate and build this scenario, it is a bit complicated but it will give you more control over what goes through the pipeline as well when authentication fails with permission issues and so on.